# Display only the values of an object using a pipe

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a following object:

```
{
  "cvaluevalve1": "D12",
  "cvaluevalve2": "D12",
  "cvaluevalve3": 0,
  "backvalue": "C07"
}
```

When I put it through the 'json' pipe {{object | json}} it comes out as it should, as an entire JSON string. However, I would like it to look more like:

```
D12-D12-0-C07
```

I know I could just display each object with {{object?.cvaluevalve1}} and so on but I would like to use a pipe for this. How can I achieve that using a pipe? Do I need a custom pipe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `Object.values(yourObject).join('-')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is something that is just going to be used in a Component and then that component is going to be used at several places, instead of creating a pipe, you could just do this:

```
obj = {
  "cvaluevalve1": "D12",
  "cvaluevalve2": "D12",
  "cvaluevalve3": 0,
  "backvalue": "C07"
}
value  = Object.values(this.obj).join('-')
```

In your template:

```
{{ value }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular 6 now has keyvalue pipe to iterate over the object

```
<div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

for more reference [keyvalue pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Answer (score 1):

In case, if you want to use a pipe here -

```
export class JsonPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(obj: any) : any{
      return Object.values(obj).join('-');
   }
}
```

If you just want the value in view anyway -

```
value = Object.values(obj).join('-'); // component.ts
{{ value }} // component.html
```

Comment: Note that this does not guarantee order for the properties.

Comment: in this case you could simply do `return Object.values(obj).join('-')`. Without need to run synchronous `forEach`

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko, thanks for your suggestion. Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this with [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#values)

```
    var obj = {
      "cvaluevalve1": "D12",
      "cvaluevalve2": "D12",
      "cvaluevalve3": 0,
      "backvalue": "C07"
    };
    var value = _.values(obj).join('-');
```